# creating 2 different types for same root element

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb

I want to create one schema file for 2 different xml's (I can split it into 2 schemas but since the root element is same, I want to keep it in one file).

now I have 2 different XML's.

```
<orderStatus shipStatus="SHIPPED/PENDING">
    <orderId>1234</orderId>
    <orderedBy>userName</orderedBy>
    <orderedOn>2012-07-23T11:35:51.000-04:00</orderedOn>
</orderStatus>
```

and the second XML is

```
<orderStatus modifyShipStatus="SUSPENDED/PENDING">
    <shipStatus>101</shipStatus>
</orderStatus>
```

how can i have 1 xsd for these 2 xmls ? When i tried to create the root element with one 1 type, it is working fine but when i try to add another type, JAXB throws error that the element is already defined. which makes sens.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends in part on what exactly you want to say, and in part on what schema language you are using:  DTDs? XSD 1.0? XSD 1.1? RelaxNG? other ...? Oh, right, I see that the question is tagged XSD, so I'll assume you're looking for an XSD solution.

If you want to say that an `orderStatus` element can have *either* the sequence `orderId`, `orderedBy`, or `orderedOn` *or* the sequence `shipStatus` as children, and that the attributes `shipStatus` and `modifyShipStatus` are optional, then saying so in a content model is straightforward.

In DTD notation (which I use here for its compactness) you would write:

```
<!ELEMENT orderStatus ((orderId, orderedBy, orderedOn) | shipStatus) >
<!ATTLIST orderStatus
          shipStatus CDATA #IMPLIED
          modifyShipStatus CDATA #IMPLIED
>
```

Or in XSD notation, write

```
<xs:element name="orderStatus" type="my:orderStatus"/>  
<xs:complexType name="orderStatus">
  <xs:choice>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="my:orderId"/>
      <xs:element ref="my:orderedBy"/>
      <xs:element ref="my:orderedOn"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="my:shipStatus"/>
  </xs:choice>
  <xs:attribute name="shipStatus"/>
  <xs:attribute name="modifyShipStatus"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Then you're done.

If you want only one of the two attributes to be allowed, or if you want the legal children to depend on whether one or the other attribute is present, things are more complicated.  (Some document designers would say that if you want that, you have two quite distinct element types which you're insisting on calling by the same name, which makes validation needlessly difficult.)

In that case, your choices are:

- Use a DTD and/or XSD 1.0 schema as described above, and express the additional constraints in the documentation, or using Schematron, or by some other method.
- Use XSD 1.1, define the content model and attributes as described above, and add assertions to say that

  - Exactly one of the attributes `shipStatus` and `modifyShipStatus` must appear.
  - The attribute `shipStatus` must appear if and only if a child named `orderId` appears.
  - The attribute `modifyShipStatus` must appear if and only if a child named `shipStatus` appears.
- Use XSD 1.1, define two distinct types for the two forms of `orderStatus` element and use conditional type assignment to say which type applies when:

The XSD will look something like this:

```
   <xs:complexType name="orderStatus1">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="my:orderId"/>
        <xs:element ref="my:orderedBy"/>
        <xs:element ref="my:orderedOn"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="shipStatus"/>
    </xs:complexType>  
    <xs:complexType name="orderStatus2">
      <xs:element ref="my:shipStatus"/>
      <xs:attribute name="modifyShipStatus"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="orderStatus">
      <xs:alternative test="@shipStatus" type="my:orderStatus1"/> 
      <xs:alternative test="@modifyShipStatus" type="my:orderStatus2"/>
    </xs:element>
```

- I'll note in passing that its enthusiasts often cite the ability of Relax NG to formulate constraints of this kind as one of its strengths.